# How to cast the wisp?

Tags: hero-siege

I'm playing Necromancer.

[image]

So you can see from my skill tree that I have the Wisp skill unlocked, however my skill bar I only have access to the Skeleton Marauder.

How do I activate the Wisp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wisp is not a spell, of which you have 4, but a proc.  There is a percent chance on ever weapon fire to generate the wisp.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is just a chance activation with you regular attack, hence, why it is not showing up on the cast bar.